aiogram 3 python - проблема с InlineKeyboardBuilder
Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой - моя неопытность, незаконченная база питона.
Не могли бы Вы помочь с InlineKeyboardBuilder.
potatiki = ('Красные', 'Зеленые', 'Желтые')

Допустим это наша таблица в базе данных.
Как с помощью InlineKeyboardBuilder сделать столько кнопок сколько в этом множестве? И также для каждой кнопки создать callback с уникальным именем?
potatiki = ('Красные', 'Зеленые', 'Желтые')

def potato():
keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
for potat in potatiki:
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=potat, callback_data="potato"))
return keyboard.adjust(3).as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)

Пытался сделать как-то так, но у каждой кнопки как видите callback один и тот же, так как же сделать чтобы его можно было менять?
Приведу пример:
Есть каталог магазина:
Шапки - (Крутые, Модные, Стильные): В инлайн кнопки созданные с помощью билдера с названиями Крутые, Модные, Стильные, которые хранились в БД, как дать им разные CallBack
Очень надеюсь на ответ, заранее всем спасибо!
UPD*
def potato():
count = 0
keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
for potat in potatiki:
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=potat, callback_data="potato" + str(count)))
    count += 1
return keyboard.adjust(3).as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)

Сделал такой код, колхоз?

Как я понял, вы пытаетесь сделать динамическую инлайн-клавиатуру? Само создание кнопок работает? Самому просто не было необходимости создавать динамическую. Так же вы должны учесть, что F.data будет реагировать на определенный callbacke, тем самым отдельно прописывать их их надо будет, или же можно сделать список со всеми callbacke, после чего брать count в функции, и уже в зависимости от count создать другие кнопки для подменю. Если я правильно понял, то должно выглядеть как-то так

Да, всё верно, спасибо

Давайте будем ориентироваться на ваш код в "UPD". Буду рассматривать самое простое решение проблемы.

Функция должна быть асинхронной (aiogram все таки)
async def potato():


Думаю, будет удобнее передавать все же список, т.е. заключать значение в квадратные скобки []:
potatiki = ['potatik1', 'potatik2' ...]


Удобнее создание кнопок осуществлять не через keyboard.add, а через keyboard.button:
keyboard.button(text=..., callback_data=...)


В callback_data будет везде 0, потому что вы добавляете 1 только после самого добавления кнопок, т.е., нужно переставить добавление значения в начало.


После всех этих манипуляций код должен выглядеть так:
async def potato():
    count = 0
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    for potat in potatiki:
        count += 1
        keyboard.button(text=potat, callback_data=f'potat_{count}')
return keyboard.adjust(3).as_markup(

